# Search json with Python and return a list

Tags: python, json, parsing

I want to search a json file for word "Leak" and the part after "for service" of each line to a list and use that list for some comparison later.

I have written a bit of code but it doesn't work quite as I want it. I don't know how to add the part that I want only to save what comes after "for service" to my code

```
def searchReport(report):
        json_data=open(report)
        jenkinsReport = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
        for id in jenkinsReport:
                memoryLeak=[]
                if "Leak" in jenkinsReport[id]: 
                        memoryLeak.append("Leak")
        return memoryLeak
```

here is the part of json file I want to parse

```
{
name: "MemorySnapshotSuite.2",
description: null,
is_critical: false,
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:44.043287Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:53.306027Z",
elapsed_time: 9.262739658355713,
state: "PASS",
cases: [
{
name: "MemorySnapshot.2",
description: null,
is_critical: false,
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:44.043441Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:53.305560Z",
elapsed_time: 9.26211929321289,
state: "FAIL",
steps: [
{
description: "...PiNS Sanity Take Memory Snapshot",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:44.043474Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:45.044551Z",
elapsed_time: 1.0010769367218018
},
{
description: "Leak of 4884K detected for service alarm-mgr",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303103Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303136Z",
elapsed_time: 0.00003218650817871094
},
{
description: "Leak of 2504K detected for service rls",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303148Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303174Z",
elapsed_time: 0.000026702880859375
},
{
description: "Leak of 1708K detected for service device-controller",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303182Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303204Z",
elapsed_time: 0.000021219253540039062
},
{
description: "Leak of 6660K detected for service slot-mgr",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303211Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303273Z",
elapsed_time: 0.00006198883056640625
},
{
description: "Leak of 6916K detected for service security-mgr",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303284Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303309Z",
elapsed_time: 0.000025272369384765625
},
{
description: "Leak of 13356K detected for service snmp-card-ra",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303322Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303400Z",
elapsed_time: 0.00007796287536621094
},
{
description: "Leak of 2680K detected for service port-manager",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303427Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303967Z",
elapsed_time: 0.0005402565002441406
},
{
description: "Memory summary: { "status": "ok", "data": { "ciena-common-dirsvc:domain-instance": [ { "instance-name": "scaler-serv", "pid": 5457, "memory-usage": "24584" }, { "instance-name": "topo-manager", "pid": 5150, "memory-usage": "20324" }, { "instance-name": "template-service", "pid": 3887, "memory-usage": "32504", "memory-diff": 528 }, { "instance-name": "alarm-mgr", "pid": 3878, "memory-usage": "24832", "memory-diff": 4884, "leak": true }, { "instance-name": "card-mgr", "pid": 3852, "memory-usage": "20836", "memory-diff": 264 }, { "instance-name": "license-svc", "pid": 3850, "memory-usage": "21964", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "comms-mgr", "pid": 3847, "memory-usage": "21172", "memory-diff": 264 }, { "instance-name": "configuration-mgr", "pid": 3842, "memory-usage": "17992", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "rls", "pid": 3839, "memory-usage": "45568", "memory-diff": 2504, "leak": true }, { "instance-name": "dns-mgr", "pid": 3838, "memory-usage": "19320", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "fiber-loss-service", "pid": 5510, "memory-usage": "20736" }, { "instance-name": "facility-manager", "pid": 3826, "memory-usage": "20860", "memory-diff": 528 }, { "instance-name": "software-mgr-ce", "pid": 3822, "memory-usage": "18352", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "device-controller", "pid": 3818, "memory-usage": "25900", "memory-diff": 1708, "leak": true }, { "instance-name": "channel-ctrl-svc", "pid": 3814, "memory-usage": "19616", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "pfg-manager", "pid": 3809, "memory-usage": "22840", "memory-diff": 264 }, { "instance-name": "shelf-mgr", "pid": 3806, "memory-usage": "23152", "memory-diff": 264 }, { "instance-name": "slot-mgr", "pid": 3799, "memory-usage": "50196", "memory-diff": 6660, "leak": true }, { "instance-name": "comms-apps-mgr", "pid": 3798, "memory-usage": "18604", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "rls-mgr", "pid": 3797, "memory-usage": "20508", "memory-diff": 792 }, { "instance-name": "lldp-mgr", "pid": 3795, "memory-usage": "20888", "memory-diff": 232 }, { "instance-name": "otdr-svc", "pid": 3793, "memory-usage": "23152", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "oms-topo-svc", "pid": 3789, "memory-usage": "27876", "memory-diff": 636 }, { "instance-name": "dependency-mgr", "pid": 3786, "memory-usage": "18140", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "demo-mgr", "pid": 3780, "memory-usage": "18724", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "dhcp-mgr", "pid": 3762, "memory-usage": "19988", "memory-diff": 96 }, { "instance-name": "wss-controller", "pid": 3755, "memory-usage": "20000", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "security-mgr", "pid": 3752, "memory-usage": "31616", "memory-diff": 6916, "leak": true }, { "instance-name": "6500r-system", "pid": 3751, "memory-usage": "19208", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "data-collector", "pid": 3748, "memory-usage": "20764", "memory-diff": 700 }, { "instance-name": "neighbour-manager", "pid": 3746, "memory-usage": "20068", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "snmp-card-ra", "pid": 3743, "memory-usage": "60436", "memory-diff": 13356, "leak": true }, { "instance-name": "graph-serv", "pid": 3742, "memory-usage": "19068", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "cpu", "pid": 3740, "memory-usage": "20688", "memory-diff": 260 }, { "instance-name": "software-mgr", "pid": 3739, "memory-usage": "22588", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "routing-mgr", "pid": 3738, "memory-usage": "20392", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "port-manager", "pid": 3737, "memory-usage": "24260", "memory-diff": 2680, "leak": true }, { "instance-name": "software-mgr-ctmp", "pid": 3735, "memory-usage": "19240", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "logging-mgr", "pid": 3732, "memory-usage": "18660", "memory-diff": 0 }, { "instance-name": "protection-svc", "pid": 3730, "memory-usage": "20364", "memory-diff": 320 }, { "instance-name": "ztp-mgr", "pid": 3723, "memory-usage": "22544", "memory-diff": 164 } ] } }",
start_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.303998Z",
end_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.304475Z",
elapsed_time: 0.0004775524139404297
}
],
errors: [
{
type: "BasicError",
raise_time: "2019-04-16T10:42:52.304459Z",
message: "Leaks detected"
}
]
}
]
}
```

EDIT: The expected output would be a list

```
memoryLeak = [alarm-mgr, rls, device-controller, slot-mgr, security-mgr, snmp-card-ra, port-manager]
```

Comment: Please post the expected output for the sample input in the question

Comment: also fix/trim the json so we could actaully load it ourselves

Comment: @ÓscarLópez added the expected output

Comment: @Nullmandon't understand what you mean by  fix/trim the json ?

Comment: the json example you provided is not valid json

Comment: @Nullman it's part of a bigger file. Do you want me to add the whole json file?

Comment: no, just fix the part you did print so its a valid json

Answer (score 0):

the provided json isnt valid, so i tried to complete it myself. assuming that the structure is:
`{"cases":[{},{},{}]}`

```
memoryLeak=[]
for entry in jenkinsReport['cases']:
    if "Leak" in entry['description']: 
        memoryLeak.append(entry['description'].split()[-1])
return memoryLeak
```

note that `memoryLeak` should be defined OUTSIDE the loop or you will recreate it everytime and end up only holding the last item

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for regular expressions.

```
import re
# iterate over events in case
for event in case:
    # get the description
    desc = event['description']
    # check that the description matches what you expect
    if re.match(r'Leak.+for service \S+', desc):
        # capture the service name
        service = re.search(r'for service (\S+)$', s).group(1)
        memoryLeak.append(service)
```